# Converting non-deterministic algorithm to deterministic

Tags: algorithms, nondeterminism

I was thinking about an non-deterministic algorithm to generate all the subsets of the $\{1..n\}$ set.

```
Subsets(n)
    S' = null
    for i = 1..n    
        u = choice(1..n)
        if u in S'
           fail
        S' = S' + u
    for_each u in S'
         print u
```

How would I convert this algorithm into a deterministic form? I know that it is a lot more complicated to convert the `choice` statement in a deterministic manner but I want to get a general idea about maybe representing it in a deterministic manner.

Answer (score 2):

Any finitely terminating non-deterministic algorithm can be made deterministic by using depth-first search on the tree of possible executions.

Or, to explain it another way: each time you have a non-deterministic choice, fork the program into multiple copies, one per possible choice.  Forking might be done by calling the operating system's `fork()` call (very expensive), or by capturing all the relevant state of the variables and storing it in a set of pending items to explore (potentially tedious to write the code), or by replacing the `choice()` with a recursive call that makes a copy of all of the relevant state (`i`, `S'`) and iteratively tries each of the possible choices (easiest to implement in this case).

Here is an example of how to implement the latter transformation.  The state at the `choice` statement is the value of `S'` and `i`.  So, we do the following:

```
search(S', i, u):
    if u in S'
        return
    S' = S' + u   # this needs to copy the set, not update it destructively
    i = i + 1
    if i>n:
        for_each u in S'
            print u
    else:
        for u in [1,2,..,n]
            search(S', i, u)

Subsets(n):
    for u in [1,2,..,n]:
        search(emptyset, 1, u)
```

Notice how `search` contains all of the code after the `choice` statement, until the next `choice` statement.  We had to rip the for-loop over i apart to make this work, but the transformation was fairly mechanical.

This is a general method that can be used on *any* terminating non-deterministic algorithm -- not just this one.

Comment: Hello! Firstly, thank you for your explanation, secondly, so for each non deterministic algoritum i have to make a copy of the current state and change something to it at the next iteration? can you show me an example of the recursive call approach for this particular problem?

Comment: @C.Cristi, I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Your opening sentence isn't true for trees that have infinite subtrees if your depth first ordering consistently chooses the infinite subtree. E.g. I might have a nondetermistic algorithm that outputs strings $1^*0$ that 50% of the time outputs 1 and recurses or just outputs 0.

Comment: @orlp, ooh, great point!  I've edited accordingly.  Thank you!